# Generate HTML Reports using TAP::Formatter::HTML and prove

Tags: perl

I have a simple test file under t/. I want to display the summary after running all the tests. For some reason, the summary is displayed before the results of "04.pl" is displayed. How do I display the summary after running all the tests?

```
==> t/test.t

#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;
plan tests => 4;

require "/home/mydir/perl5/lib/perl5/TAP/Harness.pm";
require "/home/mydir/perl5/lib/perl5/TAP/Formatter/HTML.pm";
require "/home/mydir/perl5/lib/perl5/TAP/Parser/Aggregator.pm";

my $f = TAP::Formatter::HTML->new;
$f->verbosity(-1);
$f->force_inline_css(0);

my %args = (
    formatter => $f,
    merge => 1,
);
my $a = TAP::Parser::Aggregator->new;
my $h = TAP::Harness->new(\%args);

my @files = qw[01.pl 02.pl 03.pl 04.pl];

$a->start;
$h->aggregate_tests($a, @files);
$a->stop;

done_testing(4);

my $summary = <<'END_SUMMARY';
  Total Tests:    %s
  Passed:    %s
  Failed:    %s
  Unexpectedly succeeded: %s
  END_SUMMARY

  printf $summary,
  scalar $a->total,
  scalar $a->passed,
  scalar $a->failed,
  scalar $a->todo_passed;

  ==> Output (in html format)

    1..4 
    ok 1 - First 
    ok 1 - Second 
    ok 1 - Third 
    Total Tests: 4 
    Passed: 4 
    Failed: 0 
    Unexpectedly succeeded: 0 
    ok 1 - Four
```

To run the tests, I used the 'prove' utility:
/home/mydir/perl5/bin/prove -Q --formatter=TAP::Formatter::HTML > output.html

Answer (score 2):

The following command will run all the .t files in the t/ subdirectory merging the STDOUT and STDERR (-m) and running quietly (-Q).

```
prove -m -Q --state=last --formatter=TAP::Formatter::HTML t/ > output.html
```

The simpliest way to execute it in Perl is:

```
$output = `prove -m -Q --state=last --formatter=TAP::Formatter::HTML t/`;
```

Take a look at http://perldoc.perl.org/prove.html#--state to see all possibilities of `--state` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I used the same command to generate the HTML report with graphical output. This is not the issue here. The real issue is: The summary is displayed before test # 4 is run.

Comment: You don't need to shell out to use prove. You can call it through it's module [App::prove](https://www.metacpan.org/module/App::prove).

Comment: @Brian, I invoke 'prove' using test.pl (this script uses App::Prove) . But for some reason, the summary output is not getting displayed correctly. Am I missing something here?